# Explain the sentence "Burying feelings that might get in the way of us getting our needs met"please?

Tags: sentence-meaning

As children, we want our parents to love us and take care of us. When our parents don't do this, we try to become the kind of child we think they'll love. Burying feelings that might get in the way of us getting our needs met, we create a false self—the person we present to the world.

Comment: Does it help you to consider a different phrasing? *We create a false self **by** burying feelings that might get in the way of us getting our needs met (and that false self is the person we present to the world).* Alternatively, ***We bury** feelings that might get in the way of us getting our needs met, **and by doing this** we create a false self...*

Comment: Does it mean while or when getting our needs met?

Comment: Neither, because "our" needs are not being met. Is this a language question or a social studies question?

Comment: Thank you your sarcastic reply made it clear getting the meaning implied and I got my needs met

Comment: Sorry, what exactly don't you understand about the sentence?

Comment: OP, please consider editing the question with the source of the text.

Answer (score 0):

When something is said to *get in the way of* a goal or desire, what is meant is that it is an obstacle that prevents us from attaining the goal.

Paraphrasing the original (not endorsing the theory):

If we have feelings that might in some way be an obstacle to our having our needs met, we bury (hide) those feelings, and in so doing, we present a false version of our self to the world.